# How do I get dataframe values with multiindex where some value is NOT in multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is example of my df (for example):

```
                    2000-02-01               2000-03-01             ...
                    sub_col_one sub_col_two sub_col_one sub_col_two ...
   idx_one  idx_two                             
    2       a       5           2           3           3           
    0       b       0           5           8           1           
    2       x       0           0           6           1           
    0       d       8           3           5           5       
    3       x       5           6           5           9           
    2       e       2           5           0           5           
    3       x       1           7           4           4
```

The question:
How could I get **all rows** of that df, where `idx_two` is **not** equal to `x`?

I've tried `get_level_values`, but cant get what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with name of level with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values('idx_two') != 'x']
```

Or with position of level, here `1`, because python counts from `0`:

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(1) != 'x']
```